# How to filter/capture input from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, input

I have one chatbot script in my website and I would like to store data what the user inputs to chatbot and store it to hidden input field.

At the moment it almost works, only the stored data is a bit messy.

This is what I store at the moment:

```
undefined0: What do you think about Brexit?0: What do you think about Brexit?0: What do you think about Brexit?1: hello2: Do you have an example to illustrate your point?0: What do you think about Brexit?1: hello2: Do you have an example to illustrate your point?
```

[Sample image of chatbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJYtL.jpg)

The chatbot script I use is this:
https://github.com/mrfishie/js-chatbot

This is the code for storing the chatbot text:

```
<iframe id="chatbot" scrolling="no" src="[rel index.html]" frameborder="0" height="400" width="90%"></iframe>

    $ ('#chatbot').load(function(){
        var iframe = $ ('#chatbot').contents();
        var chatData;

        iframe.find("div").change(function(){
        iframe.find('p').each(function(index) {
        chatData += (index + ': ' + $ (this).text());
        });

        $ ('input.text-input').val(chatData)  
        });
  });
```

Contents inside iframe:

```
<body>
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="chatbox" id="chatId"><p>What do you think about Brexit?</p><br></div>
        <form method="get" action="#">
            <input type="text" id="respInput" autofocus/><button type="submit" onClick="saveData()">Go</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any advice on how to store it more cleaner or to filter the text?

Comment: What do you mean by "store it more cleaner"?  What does your current `saveData` function look like?

Comment: Your `chatData` is not initialized to an empty string.  Otherwise, what are you looking for in regards to 'cleaner'?

Comment: At the moment it will run "chatData" command after every time user writes text, if I could only run the "chatData" command only once. For example it will only store data to hidden input when, user clicks Next button on page.

Next button id is " id=btn_continue "